# How can I map inner fields to the same array object in jolt?

Tags: java, json, jolt

Having this input json:

```
{
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "itemName": "Mozzz",
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "itemName": "zer",
      "quantity": 0,
      "bar": {
        "arr": [
          {
            "meta_itemName": "Small Barqs2",
            "meta_quantity": 22
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to shift the "meta_" prefixed fields up inside the orderItems object array, eliminating the **bar** and **arr** keys.

I tried this spec:

```
 [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "orderItems": {
        "*": {
          "quantity": "basket_item[#2].quantity",
          "itemName": "basket_item[#2].itemName",
          "bar": {
            "arr": {
              "*": {
                "meta_itemName": "basket_item[#2].m2",
                "meta_quantity": "basket_item[#2].m3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

but the fields renamed to m2 and m3 don't stay inside the "zer" item.

Comment: Post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This spec should work for you (tested with https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/)

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "orderItems": {
        "*": {
          "bar": {
            "arr": {
              "*": { "meta_*": "orderItems[&4].&" }
            }
          },
          "*": "orderItems[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

output for your input:

```json
{
  "orderItems" : [ {
    "itemName" : "Mozzz",
    "quantity" : 1
  }, {
    "itemName" : "zer",
    "quantity" : 0,
    "meta_itemName" : "Small Barqs2",
    "meta_quantity" : 22
  } ]
}
```